# Showing that a vector is in the span of a given set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The following vector $$\bf{w} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&{\frac{{\cos \left( {\varphi  - \theta } \right){\mkern 1mu} \sin \left( {\varphi  - \theta } \right)}}{\rho }}&{ - \frac{{\cos \left( {\varphi  - \theta } \right){\mkern 1mu} \sin \left( {\varphi  - \theta } \right)}}{\rho }}
\end{array}} \right)$$ depends on the span of these two vectors $${\bf{w}} = {\rm span}\{ \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&0&0
\end{array}} \right],\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&{ - \sin (\varphi  - \theta )}&{\sin (\varphi  - \theta )}
\end{array}} \right]\} $$
However I need to show that the vector $${\bf{\omega }} = [\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&{\cos (\varphi  - \theta )}&{ - \cos (\varphi  - \theta )}
\end{array}]$$
is also in the span of the two given vectors above. i.e. $ [1,0,0] $ and $[0,-\sin (\phi  - \theta ), \sin (\phi  - \theta )]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\omega=0[1,0,0]+(-\cot (\phi -\theta) [0,-\sin(\phi -\theta),\sin (\phi -\theta)]$.